# About Merging the files and string sequence or Loops

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need help about data merging Please help.
In one single folder, I have thousand 'CSV' files and I need to merge them (all of the files has the same name of the column)

```
import panda as pd
csv_paths = ["page1","page2", ...... till ,"page1000"]

all_data_frames = [pd.read_csv(csv_path) for csv_path in csv_paths]
merged_data_frame = pd.concat(all_data_frames)
merged_data_frame.to_csv("sondata.csv",index=False)
```

My expectation is how can I create string sequence in csv_paths list. I don't wanna write everything on my own( I mean page1.csv to page1000.csv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```py
folder = "/your/folder/path"
csv_paths  = ["{0}page{1}.csv".format(folder, ix + 1) for ix in range(1000)]
```